Field Service: How to get the Designated Work option to show on Time Slots?
I am trying to set up designated work time slots on an Operating Hours object.
A time slot should be able to be marked as a designed work type by right-clicking on it and selecting one of the options that has been added to the Designated Work field set on the service appointment object.
However, when I right-click on a time slot, the "Designated Work" option is not there.

I do not have Enhanced Scheduling and Optimisation switched on.
I have created a "TimeSlot Designated Work" Work Rule and assigned it to a Scheduling Policy.
How do I ensure that the "Designated Work" option is added to the Time Slot options list when I right-click a time slot?
Thanks

I had the same problem and this solved it https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000701252&type=1

Navigate to Setup -> Field Service Settings -> Enable "Use enhanced scheduling and optimization.".
Open "Field Service Settings" Tab -> Scheduling -> Disable "Use enhanced scheduling and optimization for all service territories" -> Save.
Navigate to Setup -> Field Service Settings -> Disable "Use enhanced scheduling and optimization."


This worked, thank you.
